# rviz error on turtlebot laptop(Asus Eee PC 1215B)

Tags: ros, turtlebot, asus

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I bought turtlebot full kit and am trying to move it.
However, I got some errors in this tutorial(Looking at Camera Data : http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/Looking%20at%20Camera%20Data).
**I couldn't launch rviz with Asus EeePC.**
How do I solve it ?

I'm using Asus EeePC 1215B(This is a default PC for turtlebot).
It has Ubuntu 10.04 and ros electric.
I've already confirmed that turtlebot can be moved by teleoperation(turtlebot_teleop),
so I think RobotSetup is correctly done.

I found one of the solution here(http://answers.ros.org/question/2109/rviz-in-ros-electric?answer=3627#3627), but I couldn't understand how to solve it in my case because of different
configuration.

Here, I show the log data including four results.

1. terminal error1 : rosrun rviz rviz (on turtlebot laptop)
2. Ogre.log : got by the command "rosrun rviz rviz -l" (on turtlebot laptop)
3. terminal error2 : rosrun rviz rviz (on workstation)
4. troubleshooting : the result I got when I followed this page(http://answers.ros.org/question/2109/rviz-in-ros-electric?answer=3627#3627)

Thanks in advance.

///////////////////////////////////////
//**terminal error (on turtlebot laptop)**
///////////////////////////////////////
**turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:~$ rosrun rviz rviz**
　　[ INFO] [1341794677.953849619]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
　　[ INFO] [1341794677.954535142]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.3
　　[ INFO] [1341794677.954618092]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
　　[ INFO] [1341794678.717732142]: Loading general config from [/home/turtlebot/.rviz/config]
　　[ INFO] [1341794678.718407144]: Loading display config from [/home/turtlebot/.rviz/display_config]
　　[ INFO] [1341794678.869544354]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
　　**[ERROR] [1341794678.945262186]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)**

////////////////////////////////
//**Ogre.log (on turtlebot laptop)**
////////////////////////////////
09:50:26: Creating resource group General
09:50:26: Creating resource group Internal
09:50:26: Creating resource group Autodetect
09:50:26: SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
09:50:26: Registering ResourceManager for type Material
09:50:26: Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
09:50:26: Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
09:50:26: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
09:50:26: OverlayElementFactory for type Panel registered.
09:50:26: OverlayElementFactory for type BorderPanel registered.
09:50:26: OverlayElementFactory for type TextArea registered.
09:50:26: Registering ResourceManager for type Font
09:50:26: ArchiveFactory for archive type FileSystem registered.
09:50:26: ArchiveFactory for archive type Zip registered.
09:50:26: DDS codec registering
09:50:26: FreeImage version: 3.10.0
09:50:26: This program uses FreeImage, a free, open source image library supporting all common bitmap formats. See http://freeimage.sourceforge.net for details
09:50:26: Supported formats: bmp,ico,jpg,jif,jpeg,jpe,jng,koa,iff,lbm,mng,pbm,pbm,pcd,pcx,pgm,pgm,png,ppm,ppm,ras,tga,targa,tif,tiff,wap,wbmp,wbm,psd,cut,xbm,xpm,gif,hdr,g3,sgi,exr,j2k,j2c,jp2
09:50:26: Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
09:50:26: Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
09:50:26: MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
09:50:26: MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
09:50:26: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
09:50:26: MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
09:50:26: MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
09:50:26: MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
**09:50:26: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): 'plugins.cfg' file not found! in ConfigFile::load at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visu

alization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/src/OgreConfigFile.cpp (line 83)

09:50:26: plugins.cfg not found, automatic plugin loading disabled.**
09:50:26: *-*-* OGRE Initialising
09:50:26: *-*-* Version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
09:50:26: Loading library RenderSystem_GL
09:50:26: Installing plugin: GL RenderSystem
09:50:26: OpenGL Rendering Subsystem created.
09:50:26: Plugin successfully installed
09:50:26: Loading library Plugin_OctreeSceneManager
09:50:26: Installing plugin: Octree & Terrain Scene Manager
09:50:26: Plugin successfully installed
09:50:26: Loading library Plugin_ParticleFX
09:50:26: Installing plugin: ParticleFX
09:50:26: Particle Emitter Type 'Point' registered
09:50:26: Particle Emitter Type 'Box' registered
09:50:26: Particle Emitter Type 'Ellipsoid' registered
09:50:26: Particle Emitter Type 'Cylinder' registered
09:50:26: Particle Emitter Type 'Ring' registered
09:50:26: Particle Emitter Type 'HollowEllipsoid' registered
09:50:26: Particle Affector Type 'LinearForce' registered
09:50:26: Particle Affector Type 'ColourFader' registered
09:50:26: Particle Affector Type 'ColourFader2' registered
09:50:26: Particle Affector Type 'ColourImage' registered
09:50:26: Particle Affector Type 'ColourInterpolator' registered
09:50:26: Particle Affector Type 'Scaler' registered
09:50:26: Particle Affector Type 'Rotator' registered
09:50:26: Particle Affector Type 'DirectionRandomiser' registered
09:50:26: Particle Affector Type 'DeflectorPlane' registered
09:50:26: Plugin successfully installed
09:50:26: Loading library Plugin_CgProgramManager
09:50:26: Installing plugin: Cg Program Manager
09:50:26: Plugin successfully installed
09:50:26: CPU Identifier & Features
09:50:26: -------------------------
09:50:26:  *   CPU ID: AuthenticAMD: AMD E-450 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
09:50:26:  *      SSE: yes
09:50:26:  *     SSE2: yes
09:50:26:  *     SSE3: yes
09:50:26:  *      MMX: yes
09:50:26:  *   MMXEXT: yes
09:50:26:  *    3DNOW: no
09:50:26:  * 3DNOWEXT: no
09:50:26:  *     CMOV: yes
09:50:26:  *      TSC: yes
09:50:26:  *      FPU: yes
09:50:26:  *      PRO: yes
09:50:26:  *       HT: no
09:50:26: -------------------------
09:50:26: ******************************
*** Starting GLX Subsystem ***
******************************
09:50:26: Creating resource group ogre_tools
09:50:26: Added resource location '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre_tools/media' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'ogre_tools'
09:50:26: Added resource location '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre_tools/media/fonts' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'ogre_tools'
09:50:26: Added resource location '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre_tools/media/models' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'ogre_tools'
09:50:26: Added resource location '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre_tools/media/materials' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'ogre_tools'
09:50:26: Added resource location '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre_tools/media/materials/scripts' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'ogre_tools'
09:50:26: Added resource location '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre_tools/media/materials/programs' of type 'FileSystem' to resource group 'ogre_tools'
09:50:26: GLRenderSystem::_createRenderWindow "OgreRenderWindow1", 1024x768 windowed  miscParams: macAPI=carbon parentWindowHandle=73400362
**09:50:27: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/elect

ric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)**

//////////////////////////////////
//**terminal error (I typed the following command after I remotely logged in turtlebot laptop using ssh.)**
//////////////////////////////////
**turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:~$ rosrun rviz rviz**
　　**Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?**

///////////////////////////////////////////////
//**trouble shooting (on turtlebot laptop)**
///////////////////////////////////////////////
**turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:~$ glxinfo | grep version**
　　server glx version string: 1.2
　　client glx version string: 1.4
　　GLX version: 1.2
　　**OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 7.7.1)**

**turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:~$ roscd rviz ; ldd bin/rviz | grep libGL**
　　libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f64b43df000)
　　libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f64b416e000)

**turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz$ ls -l /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1**
　　**lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 2012-02-14 23:33 /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2**

**turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz$ ls -l /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1.2**
　　**-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 527200 2010-04-29 14:54 /usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so.1.2**

**turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz$ ls /usr/lib/mesa**
　　ld.so.conf  libGL.so  libGL.so.1  libGL.so.1.2

**turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz$ cd /usr/lib/nvidia
turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:/usr/lib/nvidia$ ls**
　　pre-install

*****additional information*****
Laptop on turtlebot(I call 'turtlebot laptop' here)
　　Asus EeePC 1215B (Ubuntu10.04, ROS Electric)(This PC cannot launch rviz.)
and driver is default one...
**turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:~@lspci | grep VGA**
　　00:01.0 VGA compativle controller: ATI Technologies Inc Device 9806
(I'm sorry I don't know how to check the version. How can I do it?)

Laptop in remote place(I call 'workstation' here)
　　Dell Latitude E6510 Ubuntu10.04, ROS Electric) (This PC has a video card called nVidia NVS 3100M and is installed nVidia driver. It could launch rviz if it were alone.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38216/rviz-error-on-turtlebot-laptop(asus-eee-pc-1215b)/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-08**:
Could you please reformat your posting? For terminal output please prefix all lines with '    ' (four spaces) to preserve its formatting. A blockquote (prefix lines with a '>') is also acceptable. See [markdown/syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) for more information.

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2012-07-09**:
Thank you for your advice, ipso.
I made it and added some info.If it doesn't look good, please say it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<s>`rviz` needs a working OpenGL setup, which means you need a proper installation of the drivers of your graphics card. The Radeon of the [EeePC 1215B](http://www.asus.nl/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1215B/) should be capable of running rviz, but it most likely needs the proprietary AMD drivers for it (the open-source drivers don't provide sufficient 3D acceleration as of this time AFAIK).</s>

The output of `glxinfo` you posted indicates that you're currently making use of the default Mesa drivers, which is insufficient for rviz / OpenGL.

EDIT3: all wrong, OpenGL was working, OGRE needed `OGRE_RTT_MODE=Copy` again. See @weiin's answer (and the comments).

---

EDIT:

```
//terminal result (on workstation)
turtlebot@turtlebot-laptop:~$ rosrun rviz rviz Error: Unable to initialize 
gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

Is this in a SSH session from your workstation to the EeePC? If so, this error is 'normal': your SSH session has no access to any running X instances.

---

EDIT2: Perhaps you should provide some more info on your setup. Which drivers have you installed, and which versions are they? What OS are you running? etc

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-07-08**:
I don't think the default Mesa drivers are insufficient. My glxinfo output is the same (OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.7.1) and I run rviz quite fine. Running 'glxgears' should show whether OpenGL can work on the current drivers

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-08**:
Ok, that's why I added that my comment was 'as far as I know'. Perhaps you could post some more information on your setup (if it is relevant)?

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2012-07-09**:
Thank you for your comments, ipso and weiin.

> Is this in a SSH session ... ?
> Yes, exactly. Thank you, I got it.

> Which drivers ... ?
> I added some infor the bottom of the above sentences.

I ran 'glxgears' and it worked well.